# Cyclic import in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have the following directory structure:

```
my-game/
  __init__.py
  logic/
    __init__.py
    game.py
    player.py
```

`game.py` and `player.py` have import dependency on each other (cyclic imports).

`game.py` has the following definition.

```
from logic.player import RandomPlayer, InteractivePlayer

T = 8

class Game:
  def __init__(self, p1, p2)
    ...

# some other things

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = RandomPlayer()
  p2 = InteractivePlayer()
  g = Game(p1, p2)
  ...
```

`player.py` is as follows:

```
from logic.game import T

class Player:
  def __init__(self):
    ...

class RandomPlayer(Player):
  def __init__(self):
    ...

class InteractivePlayer(Player):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
```

I am trying to run the game from `logic/` directory but I get the following error.

```
$ python3 game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from logic.player import RandomPlayer, InteractivePlayer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logic'
```

I then tried running `game.py` from the directory higher up (`my-game/`).

```
$ python3 logic/game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logic/game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from logic.player import RandomPlayer, InteractivePlayer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logic'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make these cyclic imports work?

I have also tried using this import in `player.py`

```
from .game import T
```

and using

```
from .player import RandomPlayer, InteractivePlayer
```

in `game.py`.

In this case, I get a different error. For example, when running from `my-game/`,

```
$ python3 logic/game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logic/game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .player import RandomPlayer, InteractivePlayer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.player'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I get a similar error when running from `logic/` directory.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) post but didn't understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are made a circulair import in your code try to remove it from your import 
Vist this link you can find some other info about circular import :[Remove python circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996053/remove-python-circular-import)